# Let's get critical: Mar 2015 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Project Management Stack Exchange](http://pm.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://pm.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Who is reponsible when the team doesn't implement the Scrum Master's ideas for continuous improvement?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/13955/who-is-reponsible-when-the-team-doesnt-implement-the-scrum-masters-ideas-for-c)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [What level of analysis should the development team expect before being asked to estimate and develop a story?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/14070/what-level-of-analysis-should-the-development-team-expect-before-being-asked-to)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Project Sign-off / UAT completion takes very long](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/14152/project-sign-off-uat-completion-takes-very-long)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Is it necessary to address all three questions every day in the Scrum?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/13993/is-it-necessary-to-address-all-three-questions-every-day-in-the-scrum)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Team consistently exceeding their WIP limit](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/14049/team-consistently-exceeding-their-wip-limit)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [How to repay technical debt still delivering features?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/14106/how-to-repay-technical-debt-still-delivering-features)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Documenting diversions or delays from a schedule?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/14124/documenting-diversions-or-delays-from-a-schedule)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Who determines task dependency?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/14123/who-determines-task-dependency)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [How to improve a Scrum-Team with a Product Owner who lacks authority](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/14099/how-to-improve-a-scrum-team-with-a-product-owner-who-lacks-authority)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [What is the process of schedule management with clients who aren't very responsive?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/14161/what-is-the-process-of-schedule-management-with-clients-who-arent-very-responsi)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)

---